# PyPlot throws an error when DataFrame-Column has missing values

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I have the following problem:

I would like to plot a variable from a Dataframe with missing values, which are denoted as "NA". However, if I just go ahead and use with Pyplot

```
x = df[df[:country] .== "Belgium",:year]
y = df[df[:country] .== "Belgium",:hpNormLog]
plot(x, y, "b-", linewidth=2)
```

I get the following error message:

> ```
> PyError (:PyObject_Call) <class 'TypeError'> TypeError("float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PyCall.jlwrap'",)
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3154, in plot
> ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1811, in inner
> return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1425, in plot
> self.add_line(line)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1708, in add_line
> self._update_line_limits(line)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1730, in _update_line_limits
> path = line.get_path()   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 925, in get_path
> self.recache()   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 621, in recache
> y = np.asarray(yconv, np.float_)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeri...
> ```

I would be very grateful, if I had a solution around it.

Best,
Ilja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following solution. I am not deep enough into how Julia works, so I can only say what works and what does not. Arrays with NaN can be plotted with the code written above, columns of DataFrames however do not permit the same thing. The column needs to be converted to an Array, before it can be plotted with missing values. The following code solves the problem:

```
x = df[df[:country] .== "Belgium",:year]
ytest = df[df[:country] .== "Belgium",:hpNormLog]
y = convert(Array,ytest,NaN)
plot(x, y, "b-", linewidth=2)
```

x does not contain missing values and therefore I can keep using the DataFrame, but y does contain missing values, so it needs to be converted to an Array. The third argument of convert specifies to what missing values should be converted, in this case to NaN.

Comment: This looks correct -- the basic issue is that PyCall doesn't/won't [know anything about the DataFrame NA type](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/issues/154). FYI, there's a Pandas wrapper that might be of interest: https://github.com/JuliaPy/Pandas.jl

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will have a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you perform error-handling?

```
try:
   plot(x, y, "b-", linewidth=2)
except PyError:
   pass
```

Escape the error when it works most of the time for your input but skip plotting of "NA"-values....